# Bug in QCombobox with checkboxes

Tags: qt

I am trying to use the following example to create a QComboBox with checkboxes
http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/ModelView/ComboBoxOfCheckBoxes

The only difference is the QComboBox is editable.
And when checkboxes are checked/unchecked, I want to update the QComboBox text with space separated text of choices.

For example, if "item1" & "item3" are checked, the QComboBox text gets updated to "item1 item3"

I am doing this by changing the implementation of ::slot_changed() in the example to the following

```
void MyWidget::slot_changed(const QModelIndex& topLeft, const QModelIndex&  bottomRight)
{
  QString selectedItems;
  std::vector<QStandardItem*>::const_iterator it;
  for (it = this->Items.begin(); it != this->Items.end(); it++) {
      QStandardItem* item = *it;
      if (item->checkState() == Qt::Checked) {
          selectedItems.append(item->text());
          selectedItems.append(" ");
      } 
  }
  itemCB->setEditText(selectedItems);
}

MyWidget:MyWidget() {
....
    itemCB = new QComboBox;
    itemCB->setEditable(true);


    QStringList itemNames;
    itemNames <<  "item1" << "item2" << "item3" << "item4" << "item5";

    QStandardItemModel *itemsModel = new QStandardItemModel;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.size(); i++) {
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem;
        item->setText(itemNames.at(i));
        item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
        item->setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);
        itemsModel->insertRow(i, item);
        items.push_back(item);
    }

    connect(itemsModel, SIGNAL(dataChanged(const QModelIndex&, const QModelIndex&)), this, SLOT(slot_changed(const QModelIndex&, const QModelIndex&)));

    itemsCB->setModel(itemsModel);
}
```

This seems to work for the most part except when I check/uncheck "item1". The combobox text shows only "item1" even if others are checked.

Here's a specific example

```
Check "item1" "item2" "item3"
Combobox text shows "item1 item2 item3"
Uncheck "item2"
Comboxbox text shows "item1 item3"
Uncheck "item1"
Combobox text incorrectly shows "item1" instead of "item3"
Check "item1" again
Combobox text still incorrectly shows "item1" instead of "item1 item3"
Check "item2"
Now Combobox text correctly shows "item1 item2 item3"
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: can you show your definition of `itemCB` and how the slot is hooked up

Comment: Added to original question. Thanks!

Comment: I think the setEditable and the setModel are clashing? You should remove the call to setModel()

Comment: please, show complete code

Comment: @tinkertime, if I remove the setModel call, how would I get the list of checkboxes

Comment: @eyllanesc, that is pretty much the complete relevant code

Comment: @PdxEngineer 
There are members that in your code are not defined, to see if it is a bug and no error of your code, please supply your complete code.